# Migration from MySQL 5.6.35 to MariaDB 10.6.3 - Queries not working

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-migration, mariadb-10.6

I recently migrated DB servers from MySQL 5.6.35 to MariaDB 10.6.3

I have found that few queries which used to run quick on MySQL is now very slow or not working in MariaDB.
It gives:

> Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query.

I have even increased the DBMS connection read timeout interval from
Edit -> Preferences. Still the query gives the same error. The query contains high number of outer joins and I think that could be an issue.

Overall DB size is less than 5GB and the number of rows per table are less than 10k.

I have run `MySQL` tuner script for `MariaDB` server and these are the recommendations reported by the tool.

**

```
>       
>     
>               perl mysqltuner.pl
>                      >>  MySQLTuner 1.8.1 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
>                      >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.pl/
>                      >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
>                     
>                     [--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script 
>         [OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.6.3-MariaDB 
>         [OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture
>                     
>                     -------- Log file Recommendations ----------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------   [OK] Log file /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log exists  [--] Log file: /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log(10M)  [OK] Log
> file /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log is not empty  [OK] Log file
> /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log is smaller than 32 Mb  [OK] Log file
> /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log is readable.  [!!]
> /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log contains 90 warning(s).  [!!]
> /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log contains 12 error(s).  [--] 0 start(s)
> detected in /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log  [--] 0 shutdown(s) detected
> in /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
>                     
>                     -------- Storage Engine Statistics ---------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------   [--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM+PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA+SEQUENCE  [--] Data in Aria tables: 32.0K (Tables: 1)  [--] Data in MyISAM tables: 287.0K (Tables:
> 8)  [--] Data in InnoDB tables: 4.5G (Tables: 900)  [OK] Total
> fragmented tables: 0
>                     
>                     -------- Analysis Performance Metrics ------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------  [--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF  [OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
>                     
>                     -------- Security Recommendations ----------------------------------------------                                                                                        -------------------- 
>         [OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users  [OK] All database users have passwords assigned  [!!] User 'user'@%
> does not specify hostname restrictions.  [!!] User 'root'@% does not
> specify hostname restrictions.  [!!] User 'support'@% does not specify
> hostname restrictions.  [!!] There is no basic password file list!
>                     
>                     -------- CVE Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
>          [--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined
>                     
>                     -------- Performance Metrics ---------------------------------------------------                                                                                        -------------------- 
>         [--] Up for: 44d 22h 1m 57s (38M q [9.997 qps], 107K conn, TX: 212G, RX: 36G)  [--] Reads / Writes: 99% / 1%  [--] Binary logging is
> disabled  [--] Physical Memory     : 7.6G  [--] Max MySQL memory    :
> 18.9G  [--] Other process memory: 0B  [--] Total buffers: 417.0M global + 18.9M per thread (1000 max threads)  [--] P_S Max memory
> usage: 0B  [--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B  [OK] Maximum
> reached memory usage: 4.4G (58.64% of installed RAM)  [!!] Maximum
> possible memory usage: 18.9G (249.66% of installed RAM)  [!!] Overall
> possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory  [OK] Slow
> queries: 0% (841/38M)  [OK] Highest usage of available connections:
> 21% (218/1000)  [OK] Aborted connections: 0.01%  (15/107805)  [!!]
> name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each
> new connection and can reduce performance  [OK] Query cache is
> disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor
> machines.  [OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (33 temp sorts /
> 1M sorts)  [!!] Joins performed without indexes: 383010  [OK]
> Temporary tables created on disk: 9% (1M on disk / 19M total)  [OK]
> Thread cache hit rate: 99% (935 created / 107K connections) [OK] Table
> cache hit rate: 99% (181M hits / 181M requests)  [!!]
> table_definition_cache(400) is lower than number of tables(1224)  [OK]
> Open file limit used: 0% (33/32K)  [OK] Table locks acquired
> immediately: 100% (25K immediate / 25K locks)
>                     
>                     -------- Performance schema ----------------------------------------------------                                                                                        -------------------- 
>         [--] Performance schema is disabled.  [--] Memory used by P_S: 0B  [--] Sys schema is installed.
>                     
>                     -------- ThreadPool Metrics ----------------------------------------------------                                                                                        -------------------- 
>         [--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.  [--] Thread Pool Size: 4 thread(s).  [--] Using default value is good enough for your version
> (10.6.3-MariaDB)
>                     
>                     -------- MyISAM Metrics --------------------------------------------------------                                                                                        -------------------- 
>         [!!] Key buffer used: 18.2% (24M used / 134M cache)  [OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/58.0K  [OK] Read Key buffer
> hit rate: 100.0% (17K cached / 0 reads)  [!!] Write Key buffer hit
> rate: 1.0% (8K cached / 92 writes)
>                     
>                     -------- InnoDB Metrics --------------------------------------------------------                                                                                        -------------------- 
>         [--] InnoDB is enabled.  [OK] InnoDB File per table is activated  [!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/4.5G  [!!]
> Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (75 %): 96.0M *
> 1/128. 0M should be equal to 25%  [--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool
> Chunk : 1 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s) [OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size
> aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size &
> Innodb_buffer_pool_instances  [OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency:
> 99.89% (127064097429 hits/ 127199499037 total)  [OK] InnoDB Write log efficiency: 98.65% (6576119 hits/ 6666329 total)  [OK] InnoDB log
> waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 90210 writes)
>                     
>                     -------- Aria Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------                                                                                        -------------------- 
>         [--] Aria Storage Engine is enabled.  [OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/352.0K  [OK] Aria pagecache hit rate:
> 97.3% (9M cached / 255K reads)
>                     
>                     -------- TokuDB Metrics --------------------------------------------------------                                                                                        -------------------- 
>         [--] TokuDB is disabled.
>                     
>                     -------- XtraDB Metrics --------------------------------------------------------                                                                                        -------------------- 
>         [--] XtraDB is disabled.
>                     
>                     -------- Galera Metrics --------------------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
>          [--] Galera is disabled.
>                     
>                     -------- Replication Metrics ---------------------------------------------------                                                                                        --------------------
>          [--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO  [--] No replication slave(s) for this server.  [--] Binlog format: MIXED  [--] XA support
> enabled: ON  [--] Semi synchronous replication Master: OFF  [--] Semi
> synchronous replication Slave: OFF  [--] This is a standalone server
>                     
>                     -------- Recommendations -------------------------------------------------------                                                                                        -------------------- 
>         General recommendations:
>         Check warning line(s) in /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log file
>         Check error line(s) in /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log file
>         Restrict Host for 'user'@'%' to 'user'@LimitedIPRangeOrLocalhost
>         RENAME USER 'user'@'%' TO 'user'@LimitedIPRangeOrLocalhost;
>         Restrict Host for 'root'@'%' to 'root'@LimitedIPRangeOrLocalhost
>         RENAME USER 'root'@'%' TO 'root'@LimitedIPRangeOrLocalhost;
>         Restrict Host for 'support'@'%' to 'support'@LimitedIPRangeOrLocalhost
>         RENAME USER 'support'@'%' TO 'support'@LimitedIPRangeOrLocalhost;
>         Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
>         Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
>         Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
>         We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
>      See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html
>      (specially the conclusions at the bottom of the page).
>      Performance schema should be activated for better diagnostics
>      Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: Variables to adjust:   ***
> MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***   
>     *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
>       join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
>      table_definition_cache(400) > 1224 or -1 (autosizing if supported)
>      performance_schema = ON enable PFS
>      innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 4.5G) if possible.
>      innodb_log_file_size should be (=32M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files
```

**

Is the slow queries a possibility due to low JOIN Buffer size ?
Also will Thread Pooling improve the performance of the DB?
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please provide the query, `EXPLAIN SELECT...` (on both servers), and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Please post results of A) SELECT @@wait_timeout;  and  B) SELECT @@interactive_timeout;

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a suggestion rather than an answer.

I think in your case you have to check all the queries because there are very differences between `MySQL 5.6` and `MariaDB`, like the introduction of  window function:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions/

You have to check and adapt the queries.

> Is the slow queries a possibility due to low JOIN Buffer size ?
>
> It is used for queries that cannot use an index, and instead perform a
> full table scan. Increase to get faster full joins when adding indexes
> is not possible , although be aware of memory issues, since joins will
> always allocate the minimum size.
>
> `join_buffer_size` :
> https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#join_buffer_size

My suggestion is: add indexes when it is possible.

As per thread pool read more on, because I do not know which is the scenario in your case : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/thread-pool-in-mariadb/.

If you are having difficulties with specific queries ask another question, as far as I know there are no shortcut to your problem.

> Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query.
>
> Why this happens? This error appears when the connection between your
> MySQL client and database server times out. Essentially, it took too
> long for the query to return data so the connection gets dropped.
>
> Avoid the problem by refining your queries In many cases, you can
> avoid the problem entirely by refining your SQL queries. For example,
> instead of joining all the contents of two very large tables, try
> filtering out the records you don’t need. Where possible, try reducing
> the number of joins in a single query. This should have the added
> benefit of making your query easier to read. For my purposes, I’ve
> found that denormalizing content into working tables can improve the
> read performance. This avoids time-outs.
>
> Re-writing the queries isn’t always option so you can try the
> following server-side and client-side workarounds.
>
> Server-side solution If you’re an administrator for your MySQL server,
> try changing some values. The MySQL documentation suggests increasing
> the net_read_timeout or connect_timeout values on the server.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-lost-connection.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. All the columns in join clause are indexed. I checked again.

Comment: @SimsSusee i just edit the answer including the solution for `Lost connection to MySQL server during query.`. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Sim Susee, Welcome to SO.  Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G  # from 128M to accomodate more of your 5+G of data in RAM.
max_connections=500  # from 1000 because you have only used 218 concurrent connections in 44 days.
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=4  # from default of 1 to reduce mutex contention
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function, every SECOND.
```

You had 383,000+ joins not using indexes in 44 days.  Appropriate indexes are needed, likely multi-column indexes will be required.  View profile for additional assistance, please.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Wilson. I will check for indexes.

Comment: What about thread pooling. Is it required?

Comment: Generally thread pooling is NOT REQUIRED but can improve performance when properly tuned.  There are many variables to be considered.

Comment: In some queries, columns were missing indexes. Added FK references and got great performance with queries. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @SimsSusee Congratulations on your progress. Have a GREAT weekend.